# Is it possible to free up space on OneDrive from WSL2?

Tags: onedrive, wsl2

Is it possible to remove the local copy of a OneDrive file but maintain the cloud version (i.e., free up space) using WSL2?

For what it's worth, I know that I can manually remove the local copy of a file from within File Explorer using this:
[image: Free up space]
but that wouldn't be practical for my situation.

---

I have to search through a few hundred TDMS files for certain data properties. Many of those files are a few years old. Everything is on OneDrive, so most of them are present in the cloud, but not stored locally.

I have a python script that can examine a TDMS file for the properties I need, but of course I need a file to be stored locally in order to run the script on it.<sup>1</sup> OneDrive detects when I try to open a cloud file from within WSL2 and downloads it automatically, so it's easy enough to `find ... -exec` my script even on files that need to be downloaded first. The problem is that I have hundreds of files scattered throughout a bunch of different folders and totaling about 130 GB. That's more space than I have available on my local drive.

What I'd like to do is make a bash script (or whatever other tool could get the job done) that will do this for the files I pass to it:

1. Run my python script (automatically downloading the file as needed)
2. Remove the local copy (free up space)

Then I could just
`find ... -exec script.sh {} \;`
and never have more than one old data file stored locally. Step 2 is the part I'm asking about here.

---

<sup>1</sup> I'm assuming, anyway. If I'm wrong, and it turns out I can run a python script on a file that's not stored locally, that might be a good solution to my problem, too.

Comment: For Python, take a look at https://github.com/OneDrive/onedrive-sdk-python - to access files directly from the cloud, and manage the downloaded status. It looks like the "Free up space" menu option just changes the ntfs file attributes (though it might depend on how your onedrive is configured?)